# How to plot an nested array using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

I have an array from a DataFrame and I am struggling to create a multi-line graph to display the evolution of each individual over time (2007-2009) in relation to their rating. And I need to use scalarFormatter and FormatStrFormatter. Could someone please explain to me how to do this,please?
sample data:

```
columns[rank_date,rank,name,country,rating,games,birthYear,date,year]

array([['27-01-07', 6, 'Peter', 'HUN', 2749, 9, 1979,
        Timestamp('2007-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 7, 'Levon', 'ARM', 2744, 13, 1982,
        Timestamp('2007-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 8, 'Alexander', 'RUS', 2600, 15,
        1977, Timestamp('2007-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
      ['27-01-07', 6, 'Peter', 'HUN', 2980, 9, 1979,
        Timestamp('2008-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 7, 'Levon','ARM', 2880, 13, 1982,
        Timestamp('2008-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 8, 'Alexander', 'RUS', 2620, 15,
        1977, Timestamp('2008-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 6, 'Peter', 'HUN', 2900, 9, 1979,
        Timestamp('2009-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 7, 'Levon','ARM', 2800, 13, 1982,
        Timestamp('2009-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007],
       ['27-01-07', 8, 'Alexander', 'RUS', 2750, 15,
        1977, Timestamp('2009-01-27 00:00:00'), 2007]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: As seaborn needs column names to work with, you need to convert the array to a dataframe, e.g. : `df = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns=['day', 'col1', 'name', 'col3', 'country', 'elo', 'col6', 'born', 'date', 'year'])`.  Then you can call a function such as `ax=sns.lineplot(data=df, x='date', y='elo', hue='name')`.  To set a formatter, e.g. `ax.yaxis.set_majorformatter(ScalarFormatter())`.

Comment: it was already in DataFrame, i converted that in array in order to create the graph as i have been asked

Comment: Well, you shouldn't convert the dataframe to an array, as seaborn has quite some problems to work with data in that format, especially when the arrays are the rows of a dataframe. However, you could create individual arrays of the columns you're interested in and use those directly in seaborn.